# Django field widget doesn't show appropriate attribute

Tags: sql, django

I'm using Django and this is a question on how to organize your models, or equivalentely, organize tables in SQL.

At the moment I have a table where each row contains a primary key, a "value" (a float multiple of 0.01) and a "amount" (integer). This is how I need this data.

However, I need to serve it differentely. I need to sum the "amount"s over rows with the same "value".

Example, my table is

```
|   id    |   value    |   amount   |
|    1    |    1.2     |     10     |
|    2    |    1.2     |     27     |
|    3    |    1.2     |      4     |
|    4    |    1.3     |     21     |
|    5    |    1.3     |      1     |
|    6    |    1.4     |      5     |
|    7    |    1.4     |      9     |
```

For my app I need to serve this as

```
|   value    |   amount   |
|    1.2     |     41     |
|    1.3     |     22     |
|    1.4     |     14     |
```

Now my question is: What is the best way to do this? Should I generate the second table from the first every time I need to serve it? Or should I add a new model to my app that gets updated everytime my current model gets updated, and so containing redundant information but getting the job done faster?

EDIT:

```
    qb = Order.objects.filter(
        models.Q(status='B')|models.Q(status='K')
    ).filter(
        side='L', market__pk=self.pk
    ).order_by(
        '-value'
    ).values('value').annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount'))
```

The output is

```
    [{'amount_sum': 22, 'value': Decimal('1.3')}, {'amount_sum': 41, 'value': Decimal('1.2')}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
MyTable.objects.values('value').annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount'))
```

This will return a list of dictionaries that contain `value` and `amount_sum`. You can name `amount_sum` whatever.

[Django doc for Sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum)

Comment: This answers exactly what I was asking.
Follow-up question: what if I don't have that table but instead I can generate it from a query? Can I apply those same methods on a query, as opposed to on a table?

Comment: Yeah, after objects.  and before values you can filter

Comment: No wait this isn't working.
from django.db.models import [Sum][1]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I don't understand that syntax myself to be honest.

Comment: I substituted instead
from django.db.models import Sum
and still now doesn't do anything, just shows the result of the query as it is.

Comment: Oops, i tried linking to the doc in the code so it screwed up the copy paste, it should just be from django.db.models import Sum

Comment: Can you share your line of how you used it?

Comment: Ah, I see, I had an extra field that shouldn't be there. Yes, it's working now, thanks! (I've edited again to reflect the end result)